# pyspark DataFrame get original row CSV string

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm loading a CSV file to a spark DataFrame

At this point I'm doing some parsing and validation, if the validation is failed - I want to write the original CSV line to a different file

Is it possible getting the original string from the DataFrame object?

I thought about getting the ln number from the DataFrame, and extracting it from the original file

I guess it will be better using the DF object, but if not possible - extract from file

Comment: you can use textfile api of sparkContext and filter out all the invalid lines and save to a separate file

Comment: Adding on the above comment, you might need to use RDD APIs to accomplish this

Comment: Can you show how you're loading the CSV into the dataframe?

Comment: If you're sure that certain character is absent from the data, you may specify it as a delimiter and get a dataframe of a single column. For example, if `|` is absent from your data, this should work - 

    `val data = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").csv("/path/to/csv")`